# How to access files specified in a .qrc file from the c++ code?

Tags: c++, qt, resources, resource-file

I created a .qrc file in Qt 5.0.1:

```
<RCC>
<qresource>
    <file>105.ico</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

and I edited my .pro file:

```
RESOURCES += \
Icons.qrc
```

when I use the code below in my class constructor icon doesn't appear

```
 this->setWindowIcon(QIcon(":105.ico"));
```

but when I give a local file address instead of ":105.ico" icon shows up. what is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```
this->setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/105.ico"));
```

(Note the slash)

Comment: it doesn't work. my icon is located in the main directory of pro and qrc file. but it doesn't show up.

Comment: @Aidin.T Have you done a full rebuild since adding it to the `qrc`?